# 404 error when navigating the Triage queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, triage

I found a pretty low-priority bug when using the Triage review queue (it may happen in the others too).

**How to reproduce the error**

When you complete the review queue and it says the review queue is cleared, clicking the "Review" tab (next the "History" tab), if there are no more reviews, there is some JavaScript code that makes an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to the server with an undefined value. Because of this undefined value, a 404 is returned.

[image: Request in Firebug]

Obviously it doesn't actually do anything that bad. What's a 404 amongst friends? I just figure, one less unnecessary request to the Stack Exchange servers may help. It *should* be as simple as a check around the variable that was undefined.

Using: Firefox 35

I know this is a minified stack trace for when the Ajax request fires, but I figure it might help just a little:

[image: Firebug Ajax Stack Trace]

**EDIT**

I did a bit further debugging myself (because who doesn't like poking around someone else's code?) and found one spot where it seems a good spot to patch:

[image: Firebug closest culprit code]

Change the anonymous function `s` to be something like this:

```
s = function (t) {
    if (typeof t !== 'undefined')
    {
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            'url': '/posts/' + t + '/votes',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'success': r
        })
    }
},
```

**EDIT 2**

I have confirmed that this is not happening in the First Posts or Last Answers review queues.

Comment: Confirmed this doesn't happen in any of the other queues at all, it's just Triage. Also: http://puu.sh/f4tn9/a0c79f2ca5.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you are correct.  A++ debugging - a fix for this will be deployed here shortly.

Comment: I know from experience good bug reports are super useful. Can confirm the issue is fixed as of rev 2015.1.27.2226 :)